# Using JOOQ, what more do I need to prevent sql injections

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection, jooq

How is this a duplicate as i am specifically asking about JOOQ here?

I am using JOOQ in my JAVA project to handle all my PostgreSQL queries. I read in [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/work-with-the-jooq-dsl.html) article that JOOQ uses prepared statements to execute all queries.

1. Is it than safe to assume that I don't need to worry about SQL injection or user input when executing my queries?
2. I don't need to worry about escaping the user input before giving it over to JOOQ?
3. On the side note, which other vulnerabilities are there to my DB in getting user input (apart from those that are solved by prepared statements), that I should be careful of?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because this is not a question about prepared statements, but a question about the JOOQ library.  The answer by 
djkelly99 is correct.  Using JOOQ does eliminate the possibility of SQL injection as long as you do not use any of the methods annotated with `PlainSQL` which allow you to use arbitrary SQL strings.  The fact that JOOQ is safe is not because it (usually) uses prepared statements.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate, but it is asking *specifically* about jOOQ specific measures, in addition to JDBC's so I feel it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, as long as you use the provided API's correctly. It is still possible to inject plain sql queries though so be careful.

> All methods in the jOOQ API that allow for plain (unescaped, untreated) SQL contain a warning message in their relevant Javadoc

```
// This query will use bind values, internally.
create.fetch("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE ID = ? AND TITLE = ?", 5, "Animal Farm");
// This query will not use bind values, internally.
create.fetch("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE ID = 5 AND TITLE = 'Animal Farm'");
```

See JOOQ docs here for a more in depth explanation: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/bind-values/sql-injection/

2) No, see above.

3) Aside from that just beware of general DB security issues, such as user authentication/roles and storing sensitive data in an unecrypted format etc

Answer (score 2):

#### Little risk when using jOOQ as intended

When you use jOOQ as intended, then you will run into little risk of SQL injection. The intended usage is:

- Using [source code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) to generate meta data for your tables / columns, etc.
- Using the [DSL for type safe embedded SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/)

As others have mentioned, jOOQ will always use [bind variables](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/), properly [escape all inlined values (constants, literals)](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/). But again, as others have mentioned, jOOQ still allows for using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for those cases where you need to work around a lack of functionality or vendor specific feature support. In those cases, you have to be as careful as with JDBC and make sure to explicitly use bind variables and avoid string concatenation, yourself.

#### Preventing accidents with the `PlainSQLChecker` annotation processor

One way to prevent *accidentally* using plain SQL templating, and to make sure no one on the team uses it without approval is to use [jOOQ's checker framework / error prone integration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/tools/checker-framework/) and disallow all plain SQL usage by default. With Maven, you could configure this (leaving out the JDK version specific details):

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessors>
      <annotationProcessor>org.jooq.checker.PlainSQLChecker</annotationProcessor>
    </annotationProcessors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And now your code using methods like [`DSL.query(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#query(java.lang.String)) won't compile anymore, until you explicitly allow it with the [`@Allow.PlainSQL`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Allow.PlainSQL.html) annotation on the scope of your choice (method, class, package)

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to write unsafe queries, no matter what language and framework you use.

The naive way of concatenating variables into SQL creates an opportunity for SQL injection:

```
String unsafeString = "O'Reilly";
create.fetch("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE ID = 5 AND TITLE = '"+unsafeString+"'");
// results in SQL syntax error because of unmatched ' marks
```

Merely using prepared queries does NOT make an unsafe query into a safe query.

Use parameters to separate dynamic values from the SQL query. These are combined within the RDBMS at execution time. There is no way a parameter can cause an SQL injection vulnerability.

```
String unsafeString = "O'Reilly";
create.fetch("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE ID = 5 AND TITLE = ?", unsafeString);
// still OK
```

When you use parameters, you don't need to do any escaping of the variables. In fact, you *must not,* because you'll end up with escape symbols in your data.

Parameters are good for combining Java variables into an SQL query, but only in the place of an SQL scalar value. That is, where you would normally use a quoted string literal, quoted date literal, or numeric literal in your SQL, you can replace it with a parameter placeholder.

But you can't use parameters for anything else in SQL:

- Table names
- Column names
- Lists of values, for example for an `IN ( ... )` predicate—you must use one `?` placeholder per individual value in the list.
- SQL expressions
- SQL keywords

You might like my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VldxqTejybk)), or my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)

---

Re comment from @rehas:

Indeed, using prepared statements does *not* mean you are using parameters implicitly. I showed an example above (my first example), of concatenating an unsafe variable into an SQL string before it is sent to prepare().

Once the SQL string arrives in the RDBMS server, it has no way of knowing which parts of the string were legitimate and which parts were concatenated from unsafe variables. All it sees is one string containing an SQL statement.

The point of using parameters is to keep the (potentially unsafe) variables separated from the SQL string. Within the RDBMS server, the SQL string—still with parameter placeholders like `?`—is parsed. Once it's parsed, it won't be parsed again, so it's safe for strings like "O'Reilly" to be bound to the parameter placeholders without risk of causing mismatched quotes or anything. A parameters is guaranteed to be treated as a single value in the SQL execution, even if the value of the parameter contains characters that would have changed the way the query was parsed, if it had been included *before* prepare().

It's not true that using prepare() means you're always using parameters.

It's accurate to say that using parameters requires use of prepare() and execute() as separate steps. But some frameworks do both steps for you. I'm sure if you were to read the jOOQ source code, you'd see it.

Comment: When you say "Merely using prepared queries does NOT make an unsafe query into a safe query. Use parameters to separate dynamic values from the SQL query". That's a little confusing for me. Aren't prepared statements using parameters by default? For me that are two different terms for the same functionality. Or am i missing something here?

Comment: It is not true that using prepared statements makes you safe from injection.  But it does seem to be true that using JOOQ makes you safe from injection, as long as you avoid any of the methods annotated with `PlainSQL`.  An answer below provides a link to the official statement on the JOOQ site.